# Yii2 Bad Request from CSRF if page has been idle

Tags: php, yii2, csrf

I have been getting a bad request error if a page has been idle, even for short amounts of time (<5 mins), which makes for a bad user experience. Is there a way to make the CSRF key work even if the page has been idle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm assuming here there is no other request to your backend from another browser window/tab, because that could also change the CSRF)

The current CSRF is either stored in a cookie of its own or in the session. So basically it expires if the place where it is stored expires.

So basically if you have used `Request::enableCsrfCookie` (which is the default), make sure to also update the `Request::csrfCookie` settings to expire later (you can add `'expire'` for that). The basic value for this should be "session" (until the browser window closes).

If you don't use that and the CSRF is stored in the session you'll have to up the TTL of the session.

Comment: i am using session. any idea how to solve this? `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70031633/httpexception400-unable-to-verify-your-data-submission`