# HttpException:400 Unable to verify your data submission

Tags: php, yii2, csrf

My log files are filled with these errors

```
2021-11-19 12:39:42 [27.xxx.xxx.xxx][1958][gi96uqh6atadlbsg2ksjfltd9e][error][yii\web\HttpException:400] yii\web\BadRequestHttpException: Unable to verify your data submission. in /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Controller.php:218
```

Can't seem to figure out why. As i can't replicate the problem either.

I've [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459419/why-get-unable-to-verify-your-data-submission-error-in-yii2), but the solution doesn't apply to me as all my forms are created using `$form = ActiveForm::begin([])` and i'm not uploading files.

in my `<header>` i have this

```
<meta name="csrf-param" content="_csrf-frontend">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="oidpfJVSR28kMxgD4loRdgIs3TCRVITuR6Ly3Z587nLxdgIt-h8XIlFbSECzCEgHUmqaQ9InwaIYzJ2u-ySaIw==">
```

and because i use `$form = ActiveForm::begin([])`, for my form there is this hidden field

```
<form id="form-small" action="/frontend/web/search/" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf-frontend" value="oidpfJVSR28kMxgD4loRdgIs3TCRVITuR6Ly3Z587nLxdgIt-h8XIlFbSECzCEgHUmqaQ9InwaIYzJ2u-ySaIw==">
```

here is my `$form = ActiveForm::begin([])`

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => $model->formName().'-form-small',
        'action' => ['/search/default/id'],
        'method' => 'post',
        'scrollToError' => false,
        'validateOnChange' => false,
        'validateOnSubmit' => true,
        'enableClientValidation' => true,
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        'fieldConfig' => [
            'options' => [
                'tag' => false,
            ],
        ],
    ]);
```

i also have this JS in my footer. (main.php layout)

```
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '<?= \yii::$app->request->csrfToken ?>'
      }
    });
</script>
```

And i **DO NOT** want to turn CSRF off either.

in my `main.php` i have this

```
 'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
            'enableCsrfCookie' => false, 
            'enableCookieValidation' => true,
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'frontend-cookie-2021',
        ],
```

I edited [yii/framework/web/Request.php](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/552593ca3bcd9b4c9b19913e9e56de9548db59e3/framework/web/Request.php#L1841)

and added the code below before line **841**

```
echo ' -- start--';
        echo '<br><br><br>';
        print_r($trueToken); 
        echo '<br><br><br>';
print_r($this->getBodyParam($this->csrfParam));
echo '<br><br><br>';
print_r($this->getCsrfTokenFromHeader());
echo '<br><br><br>'; 
echo ' -- end--';
die;
```

every time i submit my form. the `$trueToken` token seems to be different. even when i don't refresh the page.

like below

```
-- start--
S-r869794GPYBi8voh-dXVDFLLWl8GvWhw6Qvn4c7icYu5e6sbCwLq1uf2zzTcQsAINrxuaDLprYYP_NG0Sadg==

b4GMJgf6dmn8H64oljr6uxokFC2WbQeLP4bY_SI-7Pg80Od3aLcmJIl3_mvHaKPKSmJTXtUeQsdg6LeOR2aYqQ==

b4GMJgf6dmn8H64oljr6uxokFC2WbQeLP4bY_SI-7Pg80Od3aLcmJIl3_mvHaKPKSmJTXtUeQsdg6LeOR2aYqQ==
-- end--
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why get Unable to verify your data submission error in Yii2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459419/why-get-unable-to-verify-your-data-submission-error-in-yii2) - I guess you need to send the CSRF token with the form, hence it needs to be a hidden input field

Comment: @Johannes using `$form = ActiveForm::begin([])` does add a hidden field to my form tho. and the crsf code is the same as in header too.

Comment: Are you sending these forms via a `submit` button or via AJAX? Also, can you try to `var_dump($this->request->validateCsrfToken())` and `var_dump(Yii::$app->getErrorHandler()->exception);` inside the `Controller.php` file of Yii2 and share the output here? (see https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/552593ca3bcd9b4c9b19913e9e56de9548db59e3/framework/web/Controller.php#L222-L224)

Comment: An addition based on your latest edit: Can you check in the `Network` tab of your browser's developer console if the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header is actually sent?

Comment: @Johannes `var_dump($this->request->validateCsrfToken())` gives me a `true`. `var_dump(Yii::$app->getErrorHandler()->exception);` gives me a `null`
and yes `X-CSRF_TOKEN` header is sent
`X-CSRF-Token
 EdbyZ-n6FWx-tYTlt-Yvr_PxaFpEAVeAH4FPGnBpIwlCh5k2hrdFIQvd1KbmtHbeo7cvKQdyEsxA7yBpFTFXWA==
X-Requested-With
 XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: button is also submitted via ajax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239387/discussion-between-johannes-and-sala).

Comment: You say: "My log files are filled with these errors" and "Can't seem to figure out why. As i can't replicate the problem either". Does this mean, when you post real data, there's no error? But in your log files you see, there are some attemps? Maybe someone is trying to post data without a CSRF-token. So the application is doing their job an refuses the request.

Comment: @schmauch looks like a real user submitting an ajax form. i might be wrong. is there a way to tell the difference?

Comment: or maybe i could show the user a warning or error message during the ajax post if CSRF is invalid?

Comment: @Shaho Me again. Can you please check if a CSRF cookie is set (although you have disabled this) that has this "wrong" CSRF token inside? You can also add additional logging here (https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/552593ca3bcd9b4c9b19913e9e56de9548db59e3/framework/web/Request.php#L1762-L1769) to see if it fetches the token for comparison from the session or the cookie.

Answer (score 2):

A CSRF token header name is `X-CSRF-Token`

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/552593ca3bcd9b4c9b19913e9e56de9548db59e3/framework/web/Request.php#L103

Take already generated token

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_csrf-frontend"]').attr('content')
  }
});
```

Comment: ```const getCsrfToken = () => $('meta[name="_csrf-frontend"]').attr('content');```